# Voting System Error

Tags: java

So, currently my voting system works well but now I'm getting a divide by zero code :/. This shouldn't be happening because the "Total integer always has a numerical value greater than zero (unless I'm missing Something?). Anyways I want the program to take votes and organize them as female and male voters and whether they voted for Trump or Clinton.
package vote;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class vote {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Declare Strings and Initialize
            String PCandidate1=null;
            String Gender1=null;
            String Economy1= null;


    //Declare Integer
            int Age;
            int Trump=0;
            int Clinton=0;
            int Male=0;
            int Female=0;
            int MaleT=0;
            int FemaleT=0;
            int MaleC=0;
            int FemaleC=0;
            int Young=0;



    //all data read from a dialog box comes into a string
           String svalue,output ="";
    //Need to Implement While loop to keep collecting data

           int counter=0;
            while(counter<4) {
                counter++;
   //Vote for Presidential Candidate and Tally the Votes!

    svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Will you Vote for  Clinton or  Trump?","Input Data",   JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    svalue=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Are you Male or Female (M/F)?","Input Data",   JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if (svalue.equals("trump")||(svalue.equals("Trump")))
            {
      if (svalue.equals("F")||(svalue.equals("f")))
         Trump++; 
         Female++; 
         FemaleT++;}

     if (svalue.equals("Trump")||(svalue.equals("trump")))
             {
        if (svalue.equals("M")||(svalue.equals("m")))
        MaleT++;
        Trump++;
        Male++;}

    if (svalue.equals("clinton")||(svalue.equals("Clinton"))){

        if (svalue.equals("M")||(svalue.equals("m")))
        Clinton++;
        MaleC++;
        Male++;}

     if (svalue.equals("Clinton")||(svalue.equals("clinton"))){

        if(svalue.equals("F")||(svalue.equals("f"))) 
               FemaleC++;
               Clinton++;
               Female++;}
    PCandidate1= (svalue);






    //Inpute Users Age

    svalue=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What is Your Age?","Input Data",   JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    Age=Integer.parseInt(svalue);
    if (Age<=25)
        Young++;

    // Get Users Input about State of the Economoy

    svalue=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Do you feel the economy is getting better?","Input Data",   JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    Economy1= (svalue);
            }
    int Total=Male+Female;



  //Output The Data to Form
    output=output+"Users Voted For Trump:  " + Trump +"\n"
                  + "Users Voted For Clinton: "  + Clinton+ "\n"
                  +"Total Users Polled: " +(Total)+"\n"
                  + "Male Voters: "  + Male+ "\n"
                  + "Female Voters: "  + Female+ "\n"
                  + "% Female Voters for Clinton: "  + (FemaleC/Clinton)*100+ "\n"
                  + "% Male Voters for Clinton: "  + (MaleC/Clinton)*100+ "\n"
                  + "% Female Voters for Trump: "  + (FemaleT/Total)*100+ "\n"
                  + "% Male Voters for Trump: "  + (MaleT/Total)*100+ "\n"
                  + "Number of Young People Polled: "  + Young+ "\n"
                    ;






  //write all in a dialog box



    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    output,"Output:",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    System.exit(0);
```

Comment: What if `Clinton` is zero? `(FemaleC/Clinton)`

Comment: Yes I see what you are saying, but how can I fix that? Isn't possible that all voters, vote for trump?

Comment: well, who should we trust more? 1-Compiler saying that there is a division by zero, or, 2-User telling the values are greater than zero ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of problems with your `if-statements`:

```
if (svalue.equals("clinton")||(svalue.equals("Clinton"))){

if (svalue.equals("M")||(svalue.equals("m")))
    Clinton++;
    MaleC++;
    Male++;}
```

1. You don't have brackets in your second if statement.
2. Your `if's` check whether a value is equal to both "Clinton", and "m". This means that your second `if-statement` will never be entered. So `Clinton` will never be updated and will always be zero. (And we thought it was the Russians..)

You need to have a second variable for whether the voter is male or female and check this in your second `if-statement` instead of overriding `svalue`

Side note: proper indenting will help you spot these errors

So something more like this:

```
gender =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Are you Male or Female (M/F)?","Input Data",   JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
//…
if (svalue.equals("clinton")||(svalue.equals("Clinton"))){

      if (gender.equals("M")||(gender.equals("m"))) { 
         Clinton++;
         MaleC++;
         Male++;
      }
//Etc
```